# Integral including a Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I tried to find the following integral using maple and mathematica but they would not do me the favour (only for $b=1$, but I am looking for generic real $b,a,c$).

$$\int_0^a x \sin(bx)\, J_1(cx)\,dx$$

Anybody an idea how to do it?

Comment: IMO you can assume $b=1$ without loss of generality because you could substitute $u=bx$

Comment: **Hint:** $x\cdot J_1(cx)=-\dfrac d{dc}J_0(cx)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple does the case $b=c$, maybe that is the case you intended when you said $b=1$.
$$
\int x \;\sin(cx) \;\mathrm{J}_1(cx)\;dx =
{\frac {x \big( xc\sin \left( cx \right) 
{{\rm J}_1\left(cx\right)}+xc\cos \left( cx \right) 
{{\rm J}_0\left(cx\right)}-2\,\cos \left( cx \right) 
{{\rm J}_1\left(cx\right)} \big) }{3c}}
$$